# Expressing $\int _0^{2\pi }\:f\left(ax\right)\cdot f\left(x+b\right)dx$ as Fourier coefficient

Tags: integration, functions, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I have a question from homework, which is really not understandable..
the question:
$$\int _0^{2\pi }f\left(ax\right)\cdot f\left(x+b\right)dx$$
$f$ is integrable and $2\pi$ periodic.
express the expression above as in Fourier coefficient of $f$.
I tried:
$g(x):= f(ax)$
$$\hat{g}{\left(n\right)}=\frac{1}{2\pi }\int _0^{\frac{2\pi }{a}}f\left(t\right)e^{-in\cdot \frac{a}{t}}dt\cdot \frac{1}{a}=\hat{f}{\left(n\right)\cdot \frac{1}{a}}$$
Is it true to say something like that? because the boundary of the integral is not $[0,2\pi]$ as it should be.
If it is true, then I can do the same with $f(x+b)$ and its easy.
If not, I am in a problem and did not understand :\

If my question is not understandable, I will give an example:
express fourier coefficient of $f'(x)$ as fourier coefficient   of $f(x)$, how will I do that?:
$i\cdot n\cdot \hat{f}{\left(n\right)}$
Hope it was understandable.

EDIT:
Tried what I have been told:
received this:
$$2\pi \cdot \sum _{m,n=-\infty }^{\infty }\hat{f}\left(m\right)\cdot \hat{f}\left(n\right)\cdot e^{inb}, ma+n =0$$
else, it is 0 ( it is Kroneker delta's )

Comment: Did you try substituting $f(x)=\sum_n \hat{f}(n)e^{inx}$ and evaluating the integral? 
By the way, it's `\hat{f}`, not `f\hat`.

Comment: Yea, what you said about  $f(x)$, we are supposed to do something like that, but I was a little off the calculations, let say it.. ( it was the clue in the question ).
About the hat, sorry, I didnt notice it ( you see there is a place where its good, I will fix it ).

Comment: The problem with that, think I will have two cigmas, now, the index is the problem, one of them will be with index of m and one with n, why? because you can not just multiply two cigmas with same index and receive same index. so you have to "change" one of them @runway44

Comment: Yeah, you get a double summation. I don't see how that's an issue.

Comment: @runway44 well, the problem is, I dont know how to deal with it, I receive two indexed sums, which are different, how do I "merge" them into one series?

Comment: You don't. ${}$

Comment: @runway44 I will have a bad looking answer... I will one minute write it out on my page and then write here, I will tag you once I am done :)

Comment: @runway44 look at post, now you understand why I said it?

Comment: $$\sum_{m,n} \hat{f}(m)\hat{f}(n)\frac{e^{2\pi ima}-1}{i(ma+n)}e^{inb} $$ is what I get. I am using $m$ before $n$ (because alphabet), but otherwise I notice you didn't do $-1$ when using the fundamental theorem of calculus and dropped the $in$ in front of the $b$. Also I don't see a reason to expand $e^{2\pi ima}$.

Comment: @runway44 about m before n, alrighty :)
Regarding the expansion, I thought it was a must to expand, if not, then its good. for some reason I dont know how you received $e^{inb}$, I will calculate it again and see if I get to the same result as you, a few minutes I will be back :)

Comment: Oh I just switched places, I understand how you reached it @runway44. Thanks alot, it just seems weird to me that the solution is like that :)
EDIT: wait, you missed the $ina$, no? I see it in my solution for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $2 \pi$ periodic Fourier series for $f(x)$ is

$$f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c_n\,e^{i n x}\tag{1}$$

where

$$c_n=\frac{1}{2 \pi}\int\limits_0^{2 \pi} f(t)\,e^{-i n t}\,dt\tag{2}$$

(see [Exponential_form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series#Exponential_form)) so

$$f(a x) \cdot f(x+b)=\left(\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}c_n\,e^{i n a x}\right) \cdot \left(\sum\limits_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} c_m\,e^{i m (x+b)}\right)=\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}c_n \sum\limits_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}  c_m\,\,e^{i n a x}\,e^{i m (x+b)}\tag{3}$$

and since

$$\int\limits_0^{2\pi} e^{i n a x}\, e^{i m (x+b)}\,dx=\frac{i e^{i b m} \left(1-e^{2 i \pi (a n+m)}\right)}{a n+m}\tag{4}$$

term-wise integration leads to:

$$\int\limits_0^{2\pi} f(a x) \cdot f(x+b)\,dx=\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}c_n\ \sum\limits_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} c_m\, \frac{i e^{i b m} \left(1-e^{2 i \pi (a n+m)}\right)}{a n+m}\tag{5}$$

Comment: Thanks, just to add, you can add Kroneker here and get a much more simplified answer :) ( look at what I did at post )
But the answer is good, so other people can see it :)